# Allowing just Numeric Text on Input Text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using [Jquery Numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/) plugin but I found that is not working  on FireFox 3.6 on Osx (does not allow pasting).

I'm searching a Jquery plugin or Javascript snippet that allows just Numeric Text on an Input Text field.
I have the following requirements:

1. Should allow just numeric text
2. Should NOT allow punctuation (.,)
3. Should NOT allow dashed text (-)
4. Should allow pasting just for numeric text
5. Multibrowser
6. Multiplatform

Comment: you may find this usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Comment: are dashes allowed? e.g. `-45`?

Comment: @scunliffe added in the requirements.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980038/allow-text-box-only-for-alphabets-using-jquery/2980052#2980052 with changing `a-z` to `0-9`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to dev-null-dweller i have resolved with this script:

```
jQuery('#input').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
   jQuery(this).val( jQuery(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') ); }
);
```

Comment: Came here to share almost the same thing; except that I used "\d" instead of [0-9]. :P

Answer (score 7):

**DEMO:** http://so.devilmaycode.it/allowing-just-numeric-text-on-input-text-field/

```
jQuery.fn.onlyDigits = function() {
    var k;
    // little trick just in case you want use this:
    $('<span></span>').insertAfter(this);
    var $dText = $(this).next('span').hide();
    // Really cross-browser key event handler
    function Key(e) {
        if (!e.which && ((e.charCode ||
        e.charCode === 0) ? e.charCode: e.keyCode)) {
        e.which = e.charCode || e.keyCode;
        } return e.which; }
    return $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).keydown(function(e) {
            k = Key(e);
            return (
            // Allow CTRL+V , backspace, tab, delete, arrows,
            // numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
            ( k == 86 && e.ctrlKey ) || (k == 86 && e.metaKey) || k == 8 || k == 9 || k == 46 || (k >= 37 && k <= 40 && k !== 32 ) || (k >= 48 && k <= 57) || (k >= 96 && k <= 105));
        }).keyup(function(e) {
            var value = this.value.replace(/\s+/,'-');
            // Check if pasted content is Number
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                // re-add stored digits if CTRL+V have non digits chars
                $(this).val($dText.text());
            } else { // store digits only of easy access
                $dText.empty().append(value);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

**USAGE:**

```
$("#onlydigits").onlyDigits();
```

**NOTE:**

> thanks to Insider for pointing out the past (cmd+v) for MAC

---

*key event handler **REFERENCES:***

- http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html
- http://www.hallvord.com/opera/keyevents.htm
- http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/keyboard-accessible-web-applications-3/
- http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/0.7/keyboard_events
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533927(VS.85).aspx
- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html
- http://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys-cancel2.html

Comment: i can't test it bro! i don't have a MAC and I'll never have one! ;-) can you tell me what exactly doesn't work!? grazie! ;-)

Comment: It does not allow pasting.Grazie a te :).

Comment: ok, updated one more time, now it use `e.ctrlKey` instead of `key code 17`, not sure, but it should work as expected! let me know!

Comment: hey bro, no problem, at this point, i want make it to work, but i need a little help! can you alert() the k var and see what number it give to you!?

Comment: I see 224.Sorry for the delay but i was in vacation.

Comment: hey bro! try this new fix and let me know!

Comment: jQuery normalizes `event.which` -- so your `Key` function is not necessary: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Comment: @J-P: have you tested it in all browser personally!?

Comment: To make it work on Mac OS (paste with Cmd+v), just replace (k == 224 && e.metaKey) with (k == 86 && e.metaKey). Looks like author's typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks systempuntoout.. I've fixed this with following script

```
$('#input').keyup( function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.val($this.val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));     
});
```