# Allow text box only for letters using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a text box allow only letters (a-z) using jQuery.
Any examples?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
<input name="lorem" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/g,'');">
```

And can be the same to `onblur` for evil user who like to paste instead of typing ;)

[+] Pretty jQuery code:

```
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly">
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.alphaonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
);
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use HTML attributes to attach events, especially when something as easy as jQuery is available to properly attach the event handler.

Comment: Now I used yours.On that day I did one mistake.But now I solved that.It works fine for me.

Comment: Simple solution, works great, thanks.
If someone wants to add space, use: /[^a-zA-Z ]/g

Comment: This doesn't work in Android. If you type a letter, then two non-letters, it deletes the letter.

Comment: @rybo111 Most probably you are typing first character uppercased, my solution allows only lowercase.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller google keyboard does this by default.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller to allow uppercase, you could replace [^a-z] with [^a-zA-Z]

Comment: I found it useful to add 'input' to the bind first parameter to be 'keyup blur input', it should prevent the wrong character to be seen on the screen before replacing it with ''.

Comment: Shorted and used same code in my project as jQuery('#txtfirstname').keyup(function(){        
        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); }
    );

Comment: @rybo111 if you use .on('input paste', function(){  }) instead of bind, it will work in Android as well.

Comment: for use space       /[^a-zA-Z ]/g          you must put a space between []

Answer (score 27):

## Accepted answer

The accepted answer may be short, but has some drawbacks ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UjvJ/3/)):

- The cursor moves to the end, no matter what key is pressed.
- Non-letters are displayed momentarily, then disappear.
- It is problematic on Chrome for Android (see my comment).

## Alternative

The following creates an array of allowed key codes. If the key pressed is not in the array, then the input is ignored ([see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UjvJ/5/)):

```
$(".alpha-only").on("keydown", function(event){
  // Allow controls such as backspace, tab etc.
  var arr = [8,9,16,17,20,35,36,37,38,39,40,45,46];

  // Allow letters
  for(var i = 65; i <= 90; i++){
    arr.push(i);
  }
  
  // Prevent default if not in array
  if(jQuery.inArray(event.which, arr) === -1){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Note that this allows uppercase and lowercase letters.

I have included key codes such as backspace, delete and arrow keys. You can create your own array using [this list of key codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) as a reference.

## Modify on paste only

Of course, the user can still paste non-letters (such as via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or right-click), so we still need to monitor all changes with `.on("input"...` but `replace()` *only where necessary*:

```
$(".alpha-only").on("input", function(){
  var regexp = /[^a-zA-Z]/g;
  if($(this).val().match(regexp)){
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(regexp,'') );
  }
});
```

This means we still have the undesired effect of the cursor jumping to the end, but only when the user pastes non-letters.

## Avoiding autocorrect

Certain touchscreen keyboards will do everything in their power to autocorrect the user wherever it deems necessary. Surprisingly, this may even include inputs where `autocomplete` and `autocorrect` and even `spellcheck` are off.

To get around this, I would recommend using `type="url"`, since URLs can accept upper and lower case letters but won't be auto-corrected. Then, to get around the browser trying to validate the URL, you must use `novalidate` in your `form` tag.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  How do I allow a space bar?   

I included 32 but it does not let me.  Is it because of the type="url"?

Comment: @user979431 since URLs can have spaces (they normally get converted to `%20` by the browser) then all you need to do is add a space in the regex after the `Z`

Comment: This is way better. Thanks

Comment: These two methods used together are so much better than the accepted answer!

Comment: This is good, but you should add key code 9 (tab) to the white list of keys as it will not paste anything but let the focus jump to the next input (or to the previous one when shift is down).

Comment: @Frithjof Feel free to edit the answer. Add ", tab, etc." to the line above it if the change is too minor.

Comment: Code to add space (as mentioned by rybo111):

var regexp = /[^a-z A-Z ]/g;

Answer (score 7):

To allow only lower case alphabets, call `preventDefault` on the event object if the key code is not in the range 'a'..'z'. Check between 65..90 or 'A'..'Z' too if upper case should be allowed.

Or, alternatively use one of the many [input mask plugins](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+mask+plugin) out there.

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m7QrG/).

```
​$(<selector>).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which < 97 /* a */ || e.which > 122 /* z */) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});​​​​​
```

Comment: But I cant delete it?Is it possible to delete?

Comment: Nice, but still needs some tweaks to prevent from pasting after right click

Answer (score 4):

```
// allow only  Alphabets A-Z a-z _ and space
$('.alphaonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^A-Za-z_\s]/,'') ); }   // (/[^a-z]/g,''
);
// allow only  Number 0 to 9
$('.numberonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^0-9]/,'') ); }   // (/[^a-z]/g,''
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Demonstrated below to allow only letters [a-z] using Jquery:

```js
  $(function() {
    $('#txtFirstName').keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtFirstName" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution described by `@dev-null-dweller` is working absolutely.

However, As of `jQuery 3.0`, `.bind()` method has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method for attaching event handlers to a document since `jQuery 1.7`, so its use was already discouraged.

Check deprecated methods list for jQuery 3.0 here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/

So the solution is to use `.on()` method instead `.bind()`.

If you need to bind existing elements then the code will be :

```
$('.alphaonly').on('keyup blur', function(){
    var node = $(this);
    node.val( node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') ); 
});
```

If you need to bind to dynamic elements the code will be :

```
$(document).on('keyup blur', '.alphaonly', function(){
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') );
});
```

You need to bind the event to document or some other element that already exist from the document load.

Hope this is helpful for new version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $("#test").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.charCode;
        //alert(inputValue);
        if(!((inputValue > 64 && inputValue < 91) || (inputValue > 96 && inputValue < 123)||(inputValue==32) || (inputValue==0))){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
  $("#test1").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.charCode;
        //alert(inputValue);
        if(!((inputValue > 47 && inputValue < 58) ||(inputValue==32) || (inputValue==0))){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

  $("#test3").keypress(function(event){
        var inputValue = event.charCode;
        //alert(inputValue);
        if(!((inputValue > 64 && inputValue < 91) || (inputValue > 96 && inputValue < 123)||(inputValue==32)||(inputValue > 47 && inputValue < 58) ||(inputValue==32) || (inputValue==0))){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
For letters:<input type="text" id="test">   <br>
<br>
For Numbers: <input type="text" id="test1">
<br>
<br>
For Alphanumeric: <input type="text" id="test3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the first answer.. made this..

```
<input name="lorem" class="alpha-only">

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() 
   {
        $('.alpha-only').bind('keyup input',function()
        {       
            if (this.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜ]/g)) 
            {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜ]/g, '');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This has some improvements like letters with accents, and changing "blur" for "input" corrects the Non-letters displayed momentarily, also when you select text with the mouse and dragging is corrected..

Answer (score 0):

JQuery function to allow only small and Capital Letters:

Text Field:

```
<input id="a" type="text" />
```

JQuery Function:

```
$('#a').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
           e.preventDefault();
    } else {
           var key = e.keyCode;
           if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
                e.preventDefault();
           }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Supports backspace:

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z \b]*$");
```

This option will not check mobile. So you can use a [jQuery Mask Plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) and use following code:

```
jQuery('.alpha-field, input[name=fname]').mask('Z',{translation:  {'Z': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z ]/, recursive: true}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtName").keypress(function (e) {

    var key = e.keyCode;
    if ((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 33 && key <= 47) || (key >= 58 && key <= 64) || (key >= 91 && key <= 96) || (key >= 123 && key <= 127)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(text.replace("  ", " "));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isValidName(name)) {           
   //return fail message
} else {
   //return success message
}

function isValidName(name) {
   var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
   if (regex.test(name)) {
     return true;  
   } else {
     return false; 
   }
}
```