# how to accept only alphabetical pressed keys ( for "autocomplete" purpose )

Tags: javascript, jquery

am wondering ... how to only accept alphabetical pressed keys from the keyboard .. i am using the jQuery .keypress method ... now i wanna know how to filter the passed key ...

i am trying to build a simple autocomplete plugin for jQuery ...i know a about jQuery UI, but i want to do it myself ...

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind a function to the field that replaces anything that's not in the a-z range.

```
<input name="lorem" class="alphaonly" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.alphaonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/g,'') );
});
</script>
```

Source: [Allow text box only for letters using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980038)

Answer (score 1):

In your callback, you can check the event's `keyCode` property. If you want to disallow the key being entered, simply `return false`. For example:

```
$('#element').keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.which < 65 || e.which > 90) //65=a, 90=z
        return false;
});
```

Note that this won't really work very well. The user could still paste in other text, or use a mouse-based entry device, or any number of other things.

I've edited this based on Tim Down's comment and replaced `keyCode` with `which`, which is correct across `keydown`, `keyup`, and `keypress` events.

Comment: The function name is wrong: it's `keypress`. Also, `keyCode` is the wrong property. It is only loosely related to the actual character typed. In jQuery, you want `which`, which normalizes different properties required in different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The following will prevent any character typed outside of a-z and A-Z from registering.

```
$("#your_input_id").keypress(function(e) {
    if (!/[a-z]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This won't prevent pasted or dragged text appearing. The surest way to do that is the `change` event, which is only fired once the input has lost the focus:

```
$("#your_input_id").change(function(e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]+/gi, "");
});
```

Comment: You're missing a close paren in your `if` for `keypress`! It should be: `if (!/[a-z]/i.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, it only accepts letters no special characters or numbers

```
$("#your-input-here").keypress(function (e) { return validateAlphaKeyPress(e); });

function validateAlphaKeyPress(e) {
   if (e.keyCode >= 97 && e.keyCode <= 122) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```