# Change input to uppercase without css and without seeing the text changing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem, I need to change the input on a textfield to uppercase, but I can't use css nor the usual way where you see the input changing to uppercase. The input has to appear in capitals from the beginning, I'm trying to find a way to do this but I need some help. 
I've done this but it doesn't work, the idea was to change the noncapital input to capital using a KeyboardEvent:

```
<s:textfield id="textfield1" />

$("#textfield1").keypress(function(event) {
    var isMinus = (event.keyCode >= 97) && (event.keyCode <= 122);
    if(isMinus) {

        var evento = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
        evento.initKeyboardEvent("onkeypress", true, true, window, event.keyCode - 32, event.location, "", event.repeat, event.locale);
        event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(evento);

    }

 });
```

Any tips? Thanks for reading!

Comment: textfield te genera un textbox, supongo no?

Comment: Si, es un tag de Struts 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#textfield1").keypress(function(event) {

    var isMinus = (event.keyCode >= 97) && (event.keyCode <= 122);
    if (isMinus) {

        var letra = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode-32);         

        this.value+= letra;

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

 });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kx23u3z1/

:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it to `id="textfield1"`

Also, see my answer here for more on the topic: [Allow text box only for letters using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980038/allow-text-box-only-for-letters-using-jquery/24564490#24564490)

TL;DR - don't change the input unless the user has done something wrong, or you'll adjust the cursor position and frustrate the user.