# How can we restrict to just write letters of an input? JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this sample:

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn9cy/493/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="John">
```

**CODE JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#firstname').on('input', function() {
      var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
      var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
      if(alphaExp.test(key)){
         alert("it's OK");
      }else{
        alert("Wrong");
      }
   });  
});
```

I want to check if the user types letters ... and when to display a message and if it is not right to receive a warning.

The problem is that if my site is always true and the message "wrong" (always).

What is wrong with this function?
You can help me solve this problem please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which || event.keyCode);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow text box only for letters using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980038/allow-text-box-only-for-letters-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

The `event` passed in for `on` `input` does not have `which` or `keyCode`.

Use the value of the input box to test the regex on

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstname').on('input', function() {
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    var key = this.value;
    if (alphaExp.test(key)) {
      console.log("it's OK");
    } else {
      console.log("Wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="John">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstname').on('input', function() {
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    console.log(event);
    var key = this.value;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fn9cy/499/)

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#firstname').on('input', function() {
      var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
      // this will check the above regex against the whole string 
      // in the input box this will catch copy + paste
      if(alphaExp.test(this.value)){
         alert("it's OK");
      }else{
        alert("Wrong");
      }
   });  
});
```