# Input Type - patterns

Tags: php, html

I am looking to create a field within a HTML form which allows the user to type a National Insurance number (Format example: `AB123456A`) and nothing else.

I have looked around and found the below:

```php
<input type="text" name="natin" 
    value="<?php echo"$nino";?>" 
    pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{1}" 
    class="form-control" required>
```

However this allows me to type anything in, is there a way to restrict this?

Comment: What you're looking for is an input mask - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578507/how-to-implement-an-input-with-a-mask

Comment: maybe this [plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) will be helpfull

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980038/allow-text-box-only-for-letters-using-jquery

Comment: Pattern allows you to use native html5 input validation. You can use `inputmode` to hint to the browser what keyboard to display (on mobile devices, etc). I strongly advise against trying to manipulate or block user input as it is being entered. Everyone hates forms that do this, and it causes more problems than it fixes. It is easier all around to alert the user that the value is invalid after they are done than try to limit their allowed behavior. Use a placeholder to help the user understand the expected format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2tz6sk40/) working fine!

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="natin" value="" pattern="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{2}" class="form-control" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `which allows the user to **type**` in your case, the user **can** type

Comment: I think they're after an input mask. Your demo technically does work but it won't match the format on entry