# How to autodelete comma from input type number

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm writing a function to resets input field value every time someone type character (not number). The main problem is can't use a comma for float values now. 
My function:

```
function validate_numb("name"){
    var input = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
    if(isNaN(parseInt(input))|| parseInt(input)!=input){
        document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value=" ";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value=input;
    }
}
```

In Firefox - comma is disappearing, in chrome not - what can I do about that?

Comment: Might be better to create a whitelist of key codes for this.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24564490/1094772

Comment: `function validate_numb("` is a syntax error.

Comment: `validate_numb("name")` should be `validate_numb(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood right your code might be the follow:

```
function validate_numb($name) {
    var input = document.getElementsByName($name)[0].value;
    if (isNaN(input % 1) || (input % 1) == 0) {
        document.getElementsByName($name)[0].value = " ";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByName($name)[0].value = input - (input % 1);
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmadriaga/911ratsg/)